# Rails dependent destroy on non associated objects

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations, destroy

I have two tables. 'articles' and 'bookmarks'. I want to define  association between them.

the articles table have 'doi' column which is used in bookmarks table.

articles:

```
| doi| varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL |
```

bookmarks:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_profile_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| device_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| article_doi     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| disabled_at     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

For some reasons I cannot use article's id to refer the article in bookmarks table. Now I want to add dependant destroy to all bookmarks that has that particular article's doi in the article_doi column (delete all bookmarks when an article is deleted). How can I achieve that?

**Is it neccesary that in article table 'doi' and bookmark table 'article_doi' should have the same name to be used as foreign keys?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need use "foreign_key" option

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :article_doi
end

class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, foreign_key: :article_doi
end
```

Source : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Is there a way I could enforce this in migration file too?

Comment: In article.rb, has_many :bookmarks, class_name: 'Bookmark', foreign_key: 'article_doi', dependent: :destroy. In bookmark.rb,   belongs_to :article, class_name: 'Article', foreign_key: 'article_doi'.
This always returns a nil when i do 'article.bookmarks' or 'bookmark.article'. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Article
  has_many :bookmarks, class_name: BookMarks, foreign_key: "article_doi", dependent: :destroy
end

class BookMark
  belongs_to :article, class_name: Article, foreign_key: "article_doi"
end
```